# Manage Dynamic Thumbnails on Amazon S3 / Cloudfront

Tags: image, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I just wanted to ask if there was a speedy of dynamically showing thumbnails of images uploaded on S3. Lets say profile pictures.

I have 3 sizes of these pictures being shown Actual, 150x150 and 25x25. At the moment I am dynamically resizing them on the fly on my server - not S3.

```
http://www.mydomain.com/images/25X25/image.jpg
```

Above is a URL that checks if a thumbnail exists and if not generates it. I allow only 3 sizes at the moment.

Soon we would be shifting to S3. Is such thing possible at S3 also - do I have to get the original image, resize it and then reupload on S3 - all on the fly - of course with cache enabled?

Or should I do this when I upload the actual image itself - make 2 more thumbnails (with easily readable filename lile image_25_25 and image_150_150) and upload those too along with it?

So eventually every upload results in

```
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image.jpg
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image_25_25.jpg
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image_150_150.jpg
```

Which do you think is a good option? Or Suggestions please - will be really thankfull to you all (err - always am - such an amazing place this is to get help!)

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that your approach will largely depend on what your primary goals are for making this change, what sort of upload volume you are expecting to handle, what sort of typical hit rate you have on these thumbnails, and what your constraints are regarding cost of performing this thumbnailing (i.e server resources needed to do the processing and storage costs for storing).

If the #1 most important thing is to speed-up image download times for end users, regardless of cost, then building the thumbnails on upload would probably be the best choice (possibly along with the use of Cloudfront in front of the S3 bucket).  This would also take your application out of the business of trying to dynamically serve requests for these images.  One con is obviously that the upload process may take longer for the end user (if you need the files to be created and available in S3 before indicating success to the end user), and of course you end up having to tie up server resources and storage space for every single uploaded image, regardless as to whether the image will ever be used.

If your concerns are more about utilizing the minimum amount of resources and storage, then you could continue to take the approach of using the web application to handle the image requests and create the images as needed in S3.  You could potentially use something like s3fs (with its caching functions turned on) to make these images available on a local mount of your application server to help speed up the process, but really I would advise against this dynamic serving of content approach if your overall goal is to provide the best user experience (i.e. quickest downloads).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I would go for generating and uploading thumbnails for each image upon upload and use Cloudfront in front of S3 to serve the filed. Will post results and statistics here to discuss further!

Comment: Hi @foxybagga , what path did you take eventually? i am right now in the way of making thumbs and uploading to S3 but kind of trying  to figure out the best way to do so, please share experience :)

Comment: Hello @user1725378 - generating the thumbs only when they were requested sounded the best solution to me - saved server run time and storage as well!

Comment: how can i produce the thumbs on request? does s3 support such a feature?

Comment: @user1725378 S3 is just a place to store files.  Any logic you need to generate thumbnails will need to be implemented on your end.

Comment: But then the whole point is missed. the thumbnails are for smaller traffic. if the user click on an image it loads the whole image. if the client's end need to make thumbs from the 1mb picture.. it need to load the big picture which is the worst thing traffic wise todo.

Comment: @user1725378 In my answer I clearly state that the individual use case(s) should be evaluated to determine what the best approach may be for one's needs.  I even stated that from an end-user perspective it would probably make sense to create all thumbnails on uploads as this ensures that a thumbnail is always available for use without the need to create the thumbnail on-demand.  Again, this doesn't change the fact that S3 does not create thumbnails.  One would need to implement some logic to generate thumbnails whether it be on upload, via a background process, or on-demand.

Comment: See "Pattern-3: Dynamic Thumbnailing And Encoding" following this link, it may be helpful: http://abhishek-tiwari.com/post/CloudFront-design-patterns-and-best-practices